# How to create a row on top of the grid using Kendo UI?

Tags: kendo-grid

I want to create a row on top of the grid using Kendo UI?

When I click on Add New Record button, I want always the new row to populate on top (first row of the grid), if I add one record I don't have any issue, but if I add continuously multiple records then the rows will go down (one after another).

Sample grid in my .html page:

```
    <div id="commentsDiv" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom:15px; border: 0px;">

                    <div data-role="grid"
                         data-scrollable="true"
                         data-resizable="true"
                         data-editable="inline"
                         data-toolbar="['create', 'cancel']"
                         data-columns="[
                                         { field: 'cmntTxt',                title: 'Comment',       width: 400},
                                         { field: 'createdDate' ,           title: 'Created On',    width: 125, type : 'date', 'format' : '{0: MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}'},
                                        { command: ['edit', 'destroy',],    title: 'Actions',       width: 150 }
                                     ]"
                         data-bind="source: commentsDS"
                         data-scrollable='true'
                         data-sortable='true'
                         data-filterable='true'

                         data-pageable="{ 
                                 pageSize: 15,
                                 pageSizes: [15, 50, 100, 200, 500],
                                 refresh : true,                                                         
                                 buttonCount : 5
                                 }"                
                        style="width: 100%; height: 500px">
                    </div>

    </div>
```

`data-toolbar="['create', 'cancel']"` create is ADD NEW RECORD, cancel -is Cancel changes this information is coming from kendo.all.mini.js.

When I click on add New Record button I want always the new row to populate on top (first row of the grid), if I add one record I don't have any issue, but if I add continuously multiple records then the rows will go down (one after another).

When I click add new record the following code is getting called from kendo.all.mini.js

```
    addRow: function () {
    var e,
    t,
    n,
    i,
    r,
    o,
    a = this,
    s = a.dataSource,
    l = a._editMode(),
    c = a.options.editable.createAt || '',
    d = s.pageSize(),
    u = s.view() || [];
    (a.editable && a.editable.end() || !a.editable) && ('incell' != l && a.cancelRow(), e = s.indexOf(u[0]), 'bottom' == c.toLowerCase() && (e += u.length, d && !s.options.serverPaging && u.length >= d && (e -= 1)), 0 > e && (e = s.page() > s.totalPages() ? (s.page() - 1) * d : 0), t = s.insert(e, {
    }), n = t.uid, i = a.lockedContent ? a.lockedTable : a.table, r = i.find('tr[' + dt.attr('uid') + '=' + n + ']'), o = r.children('td:not(.k-group-cell,.k-hierarchy-cell)').eq(a._firstEditableColumnIndex(r)), 'inline' === l && r.length ? a.editRow(r)  : 'popup' === l ? a.editRow(t)  : o.length && a.editCell(o), 'bottom' == c.toLowerCase() && a.lockedContent && (a.lockedContent[0].scrollTop = a.content[0].scrollTop = a.content[0].offsetHeight))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your index and then add in the values you want ( I'm just setting them to null as you can fill them in ):

```
$('#yourButton').on('click', function(){
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.insert(0, { cmntTxt: "", createdDate: "", action: "" });
});
```

Comment: Hi Keith, Thank you for responding to my question. actually in my html page - grid is having data-toolbar="['create', 'cancel']", this create is Add New Record (which is defined in kendo.all.mini.js file which came from KENDO framework, the same file is having add row function and that is getting called when i click on the button. with out touching the kendo.all.mini.js file you want me to create a new button in my html page grid?

Comment: I'm saying it would be easier to custom your own button to do what you want. You can always hide kendo controls.